# Replacing Yosemite RED/ORANGE/GREEN window buttons with standard Mac OS X icons?

Tags: ui, macos

I've tried Yosemite on my MacBook Air (testing machine). I think it is ugly, bland, and the most un-Apple-ish OS that Apple has ever released. One of the most irritating design aspects is the RED/AMBER/GREEN window buttons (Close/minimise etc) which look to me like they were designed by a child.

Are there any tricks or methods for replacing the Yosemite rendition of these Mac OS X buttons with the usual ones we are all familiar with?

Answer (score 1):

There are some applications that allow you to change the theme in OS X.

However they might need a little time to be updated for the new UI in Yosemite.

For example [Flavours](http://flavours.interacto.net) which is being updated but [isn't quite ready yet](https://interacto.zendesk.com/entries/53605899-Yosemite-and-the-future-Flavours-2).

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick theme to change the 'traffic lights' to how they were before. Here are the installment instructions:

- WARNING: I made this on MacOS Sierra 10.12.1, so using it in other versions might cause severe issues. I'm also not responsible for any bad side effects.

  1. Download this file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ortjz8deky9977r/SystemAppearance.car
  2. In Finder, go to /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearence.bundle/contents/Resources
  3. Keep a copy of SystemAppearance.car from there for any emergencies
  4. Replace the original SystemAppearance.car with the one you just downloaded
  5. Restart your Mac
  6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There's only one theme that I know of for Yosemite that changes the traffic lights:

http://www.deviantart.com/art/Yosemite-Theme-Clearify-477715451

Be careful when replacing system files like these, always backup your system and keep copies of the original files somewhere safe!

Answer (score 0):

Go into System Preferences > General > Highlight Color and select the grey graphite color.

Now your window buttons will all be grey. Hooray, no more kiddie colors!

Comment: Who ever downvoted this is a twat.